# Currency / Percent Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex, currency

I have to match values like

```
€ 6.483,00
```

OR values like

```
18,50%
```

OR, again,

```
+65,86 %
```

in a Javascript function, which I drafted as:

```
function(s) {
  return /^[0-9]?[0-9,\.]*$/.test(s);
}
```

but, obviously, it's not working... how should it be changed?

Comment: Have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079582/problem-using-jquery-calculation-with-european-formatted-numbers

Comment: nice but... it's not an answer, replacing /(-|-\$)?(\d+(\.\d{3})*(\,\d{1,})?|\,\d{1,})?/g in the above function still doesn't get my job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var sample = [
    "€ 6.483,00",
    "18,50%",
    "+65,86 %"
]
for(var i = 0; i < sample.length; i++) {
    var input = sample[i];
    var regex = /^(\u20ac ?)?\+?\d+(\.\d+)?(\,\d+)?( ?%)?$/
    console.log(input + "\t" + regex.test(input));
}
```

If there are cases that do not/should not match then let me know.

Answer (score 3):

```
^(?:€|\+)?\s*\d+(?:\.?\d{3})*(?:,\d+)?\s*%?\s*$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2ullj)

Start of the string, an optional € or +, then optional whitespace, Then there should be at list one digit, followed by an optional dot and three digits, then an optional fraction, optional whitespace, optional % more optional whitespace and then the end of the string,