# Javascript Regular expression for currency amount with spaces

Tags: javascript, regex, currency

I have this regular expression

```
/^[',",\+,<,>,\(,\*,\-,%]?([£,$,€]?\d+([\,,\.]\d+)?[£,$,€]?\s*[\-,\/,\,,\.,\+]?[\/]?\s*)+[',",\+,   <,>,\),\*,\-,%]?$/
```

It matches this very well $55.5, but in few of my test data I have some values like $ 55.5 (I mean, it has a space after $ sign).

The answers on this link are not working for me.
[Currency / Percent Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385145/currency-percent-regular-expression)

So, how can I change it to accept the spaces as well?

Comment: Change `([£,$,€]?\d+` to `([£,$,€]?\s*\d+`

Comment: The Regex looks too long for your intentions...

Comment: That's a very unwieldy regex, what are you trying to match exactly?

Comment: You don't need commas in a character class to separate the characters, if you want to add the comma, then one time is enough. A comma also don't needs to be escaped. In a character class you need only to escape the `-` and the `]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following `RegEx`:

```
/^[',",\+,<,>,\(,\*,\-,%]?([£,$,€]?\s*\d+([\,,\.]\d+)?[£,$,€]?\s*[\-,\/,\,,\.,\+]?[\/]?\s*)+[',",\+,   <,>,\),\*,\-,%]?$/
```

Let me know if it worked!

**[Demo Here](http://regexr.com/393rl)**

Comment: This will match `,,   123,456789$   %`

Comment: Why do you keep the obvious errors from the original regex in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR:

```
/^[',",\+,<,>,\(,\*,\-,%]?([£,$,€]?\s*\d+([\,,\.]\d+)?[£,$,€]?\s*[\-,\/,\,,\.,\+]?[\/]?\s*)+[',",\+,   <,>,\),\*,\-,%]?$/
```

**The science bit**

Ok, I'm guessing that you didn't construct the original regular expression, so here are the pieces of it, with the addition marked:

```
^ # match from the beginning of the string
[',",\+,<,>,\(,\*,\-,%]?    # optionally one of these symbols
(                           # start a group
   [£,$,€]?                   # optionally one of these symbols
   \s*                        # <--- NEW ADDITION: optionally one or more whitespace
   \d+                        # then one or more decimal digits
   (                          # start group 
      [\,,\.]                   # comma or a dot
      \d+                       # then one or more decimal digits
   )?                         # group optional (comma/dot and digits or neither)
   [£,$,€]?                   # optionally one of these symbols
   \s*                        # optionally whitespace
   [\-,\/,\,,\.,\+]?          # optionally one of these symbols
   [\/]?                      # optionally a /
   \s*                        # optionally whitespace
)+                          # this whole group one or more times
[',",\+,   <,>,\),\*,\-,%]? # optionally one of these symbols
$ # match to the end of the string
```

Much of this is poking about matching stuff around the currency amount, so you could reduce that.